# Formatting Recurly.js input fields

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, recurly

I am building a form to process a payment via Recurly.  The non-recurly.js fields use Bootstrap for their layout.

I can style the containing DIV to get the border and border-radius to match the Bootstrap fields but Bootstrap sets padding on input fields:

```
padding: 6px 12px;
```

...I believe that you pass styles for the actual input fields via the recurly configure so I tried this:

```
style: {
        all: {
            fontFamily: 'Verdana',
            fontSize: '14px',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            padding: '8px'
        },
        number: {
            placeholder: 'Credit card number'
        },
        month: {
            placeholder: 'Exp. Month (mm)'
        },
        year: {
            placeholder: 'Exp. Year (yy)'
        }
    }
```

...but it is just ignoring the padding.  Is there a list of "supported" style options for Recurly.js somewhere?  Anyone figured out how to get padding on the iFramed/injected input field?

Comment: From the Docs --> [STYLING CARD FIELDS](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/getting-started-1#section-styling-card-fields)

Comment: @vanburen - that (unfortunately) is an example but does not provide a comprehensive list of what you can place in the configure() call.

Answer (score 2):

Recurly has several css classes that can be styled instead. I've found that much easier than trying to use their js styling.

So I style these classes using css and ignore all js options.

```
.recurly-hosted-field        = Default styles for the div surrounding each field iframe.
.recurly-hosted-field-focus  = Applied when the user focuses on a field.
.recurly-hosted-field-number = Default styles for the div surrounding the month field iframe.
.recurly-hosted-field-month  = Default styles for the div surrounding the month field iframe.
.recurly-hosted-field-year   = Default styles for the div surrounding the year field iframe
```

Docs: https://dev.recurly.com/docs/getting-started-1
They have a table toward the bottom of this link that has these classes